# Is there a way to open terminal rather than terminal emulator?

Tags: terminal

I mean the system terminal, without the need for window manager and emulators...

On linux that was achievable via ALT+Fx, but it's not like that for OS X.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you want single user mode?

Hold s while booting the computer.